# Update foreign key column

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I can't figure out how you do this in linq-to-sql.

Simple foreign key example below.

```
CARS TABLE
Columns - CARID (PK), NAME, SIZE, MODELID(FK)


MODELS TABLE
Columns MODELID(PK), MODELNAME
```

To change the Model of the car in SQL I would

```
UPDATE CARS
SET MODELID = 'MODEL88'
WHERE CARID = 'CAR01'
```

In linq-to-sql I tried to do something similar, but the update doesn't work.

```
Car car = db.Cars.Where(x => x.CarId == "CAR01").FirstOrDefault();
Model model = db.Models.Single(c => c.ModelId == "MODEL88");
car.Model = model;
db.SubmitChanges();
```

There are no exceptions, it just doesn't do the update. Updating other fields which are not foreign keys does work e.g. size.

```
Car car = db.Cars.Where(x => x.CarId == "CAR01").FirstOrDefault();
car.Size = "22";
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, bizarre. Are the relationships set-up in the database? and is this reflected in your .DBML?

Out of curiousity, does it work if you add `car` to the `Cars` colleciton on `model`, like so:

```
Car car = db.Cars.Where(x => x.CarId == "CAR01").FirstOrDefault();
Model model = db.Models.Single(c => c.ModelId == "MODEL88");
model.Cars.Add(car)
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Parent Class: Model Child Class: Car in the dbml, I'll try the .Add now

Comment: Your answer helped because it showed I was doing nothing wrong. Re-creating everything from scratch worked so something must have been corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it will work:

```
Car car = db.Cars.Where(x => x.CarId == "CAR01").FirstOrDefault();
Model model = db.Models.Single(c => c.ModelId == "MODEL88");
car.ModelId = model.Id;
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: This returns Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.